# existing Spring MVC project into RAD + WAS

Tags: spring-mvc, websphere, websphere-7, ibm-rad

I have a question about RAD & WAS Spring MVC development. So that we have a project in SVN that was created by me in STS (eclipse), but some of our team members can't retrieve & run this Spring MVC project on their RAD (ibm tool) IDE on WebSphere Application Server 7. It requires to create an EAR to run it on WAS, but in this case there're 2 projects in project explorer; EAR project & the normal one... the normal is almost an empty project, but everything from SVN is kept under EAR project. But they can't simply access index.jsp file from WebContent folder when they try to run EAR project on WAS, it says **"Failed to find resource /index.jsp"**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When work Spring projects over RAD we do the following approach:

- We create a Dynamic Web project that contains all our Java Classes, JSP's, Spring files and some libraries that are inherent to the project. This project can be exported to a WAR and executed in containers like Apache Tomcat with no problem.
- The we create an Enterprise Application Project that contains a Web Module reference to our  Spring project, so we can run our application over IBM WAS as an EAR (although, WAS can work with WAR's too). This project only contains some configurations files and upper-level libraries.

Your Spring project should be imported in RAD's workspace as a Dynamic Web Project, and the EAR project must be created by the guys that uses RAD for development (an uploaded to SVN if you need it). If your "normal" -i.e Dynamic Web Project- is empty, you should check that the uploaded files are OK and the checkout process was normal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the other resources besides index.jsp?

You got to narrow down things?

What is the context root for your web application? Is it "/"?

Post in additional information before folks can assist you

HTH

Manglu